# android игры на html5

Tags: android

Привет, я хочу написать игру на html5, можно написать игру под андроид без java? Activity java написать на. С++ или питон? Без Ява никак?

Comment: Вы уж как-то определитесь, HTML5, C++ или питон. Насчет последнего не уверен, но для первых двух игровых фреймворков хватает. Достаточно погуглить.